# не отправляется сообщение в телеграм боте

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Я создаю бота для телеги и когда отправляю начальное сообщение нечего не происходит
вот код

```py
import COVID19Py
import telebot

covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19()
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    send_mess = f"<b>Привет {message.from_user.first_name}!</b>\nВведите страну"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, parse_mode='html')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

вроде бы всё правильно, но вот результат
[image: несколько раз отправил начальное сообщение и всё ровно нечего не работает]

Comment: впн то не забыл ? Ошибку какую выдаёт ? Код зря с токеном выкладываешь

Comment: ошибку не выдаёт просто нечего не происходит

Comment: Мб токен не тот. Код работает, если что

Comment: но я вставил правильный токен

Comment: я создал нового бота через botfather но нечего не сработало
теперь уж точно правильный токен

Comment: @E_d_u_a_r_d Ты уверен, что там нужен слэш?

Comment: да слэш нужен..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня все работает с моим токеном, но  только с VPN.[image: пруф]

Попробуйте обновить telebot и pyTelegrammBotApi(pip install pyTelegramBotAPI)

Comment: Я попробовал с vpn но всё ровно не работает

Comment: А то, что я указал вы обновили?

Comment: да я обновил, но всё уже решено

Comment: и работает без впн

Comment: у меня без VPN не работало никогда